# Mouseover problem with Vue autocomplete list

Tags: javascript, vue.js, autocomplete, vuejs3, vue-component

I just programmed a Vue component to autocomplete from a list of names. The component works quite well but I still have something I want to improve. If the user hovers an element with the mouse, that element gets selected and this is correct. But if the element is being hovered by the mouse pointer and the user suddently uses the arrow keys to begin navigating throughout the list of names with the keyboard, the mouse selection remains highlighted, even if another element is being selected giving an incorrect visual result of two highlighted elements. This will not cause problems or errors, but it will confuse the user and I would like to fix it. I tried several methods but none works. But first let show the code.

```
/* SelectAutocomplete.vue */
<template>
    <div class="autocomplete">
        <!-- In the setup below, the prevent modifier ensures that the default behavior of the arrow keys is prevented, allowing your custom key event handling to take effect. -->
        <input v-model="search" 
            @input="onChange" 
            @keydown.down.prevent="onArrowDown" 
            @keydown.up.prevent="onArrowUp"
            @keydown.enter.prevent="selectItem" 
            @keydown.tab.prevent="selectItem" 
            type="text"
            ref="inputField"
        />
        <!-- The mouseover event here is very important, because it allows
        to select the element on pressing enter or tab, even if this takes
        more than that -->
        <ul v-show="isOpen" 
            class="autocomplete-results" 
            ref="resultsList"
            @mouseout="moveMouseOutside"
        >
            <!-- The result variable is only used to cycle through the feteched
            result and to populate the dom list. result is not needed to actually
            select an element because its index is used instead -->
            <li v-for="(result, i) in results" 
                :key="i" 
                @click="selectItem()" 
                @mouseover="selectedIndex = i"
                class="autocomplete-result" 
                :class="{ 'is-active': i === selectedIndex }">
                {{ result }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="nextEle" v-model="nextInputValue" ref="nextInputElement" type="text"
            placeholder="this does nothing it just illustrates the focus" />
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'SearchAutocomplete',
    props: {
        items: {
            type: Array,
            required: false,
            default: () => [],
        },
    },
    data() {
        /* Here we initialize all the variables */
        return {
            search: '',     // initialize search results
            results: [],    // receive an array
            isOpen: false,  // start with the component closed
            selectedIndex: -1,
            nextInputValue: '',
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        document.addEventListener('click', this.handleClickOutside);
    },
    beforeUnmount() {
        document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClickOutside);
    },
    methods: {
        /* No longer needed *//*setResult(result) {console.log(result);this.selectItem()},*/

        filterResults() {
            this.results = this.items.filter(item => item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1);
        },

        onChange() {
            this.filterResults();
            // Check for non-empty input or non-empty results
            if (this.search.trim() !== '' || this.results.length > 0) {
                this.isOpen = true;
            } else {
                this.selectedIndex = -1;
                this.isOpen = false;
            }
        },

        handleClickOutside(event) {
            if (!this.$el.contains(event.target)) {
                this.selectedIndex = -1;
                this.isOpen = false;
            }
        },
        onArrowDown() {

            if (this.selectedIndex < this.results.length) {
                this.selectedIndex++;
            }
        },

        onArrowUp() {
            if (this.selectedIndex > 0) {
                this.selectedIndex--;
            }
        },

        onEnter() {
            this.search = this.results[this.selectedIndex];
            this.selectedIndex = -1;
            this.isOpen = false;
        },

        selectItem() {
            if (this.selectedIndex !== -1) {
                this.search = this.results[this.selectedIndex];

                this.isOpen = false;
                // Focus on the next input element
                this.$nextTick(() => {
                    const nextInput = this.$refs.nextInputElement;
                    if(nextInput && nextInput.focus){
                        nextInput.focus();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    },
};
</script>
<style>
.autocomplete {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* This style applies to the entire list */
.autocomplete-results {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
    width: 300px;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    /* On overflow, will add a vertical scrollbar automatically */
    overflow-x: auto;
    /* On overflow, will add a horizontal scrollbar automatically */
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    /* A nice border around the suggestion list */
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

/* This style applies to each element of the list */
.autocomplete-result {
    padding: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
}

/* When the mouse hovers and navigate through the list, each item will be highlighted
    with a nice green color.*/
.is-active,
.autocomplete-result:hover {
    background-color: #4AAE98;
    color: white;
}

/* This will apply when the user navigates through the suggestion list using a keyboard */
/*.highlighted {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}*/

.nextele {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 80%;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    /* To prevent the input from growing when padding is added */
}
</style>
```

And now the App.js, even if it's not related to the issue, but it's always good to show it:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <SearchAutocomplete :items="csvData"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import SearchAutocomplete from './components/SearchAutocomplete.vue'
//import Papa from 'papaparse'
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: {
        SearchAutocomplete
    },
    data() {
        return {
            csvData: []
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.fetchCSVData();
    },
    methods: {
        fetchCSVData() {
            axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/process-csv/')
                .then(response => {
                    /* Here response.data is a string, but, in reality I should receive an array */
                    console.log(typeof(response.data));
                    // console.log(response.data);
                    this.csvData = response.data;
                    //console.log(response.data);
                    console.log('Ok');
                })
                .catch(error=> {
                    console.error('Error fetching CSV data:', error);
                });
        },
        
    }
}
</script>
```

Here's, what I did to solve the issue:

1. I tried to remove the css is-active class. I defined a function clearHoverSelection() that gets called from inside the onArrowUp and onArrowDown methods

```
  clearHoverSelection() {
    this.$refs.resultsList.querySelectorAll('.autocomplete-result').forEach((element, index) => {
      if (index !== this.selectedIndex) {
        element.classList.remove('is-active');
      }
    });
  },
```

but it produces no effect.

2. I tried to remove the focus when arrow down keys are pressed but I quickly realized that this does not fix anything, because the user still needs to navigate throughtout the list and therefore the focus must remain in the component.
3. I created a method called moveMouseOutside, to simulate a mouseout event, but it produces no effect at all

```
        moveMouseOutside(){
            const resultsList = this.$refs.resultsList;
            if(resultsList){
                const mouseOutEvent = new MouseEvent("mouseout", {
                    bubbles: true,
                    cancelable: true,
                    view: window,
                });
                resultsList.dispatchEvent(mouseOutEvent);
            }
        },
```

The only solution I can imagine is to programmatically put the mouse pointer outside the component, so this latter still keeps the focus and the element that was selected by the mouse is no longer hovered. But I don't know how to do it.

Has someone already faced this kind of issue? Please help.

Comment: it seems no problem whith your code ,checking your css file if it contains  :hover,

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution, it was to remove the `.autocomplete-result:hover` from

```
.is-active,
.autocomplete-result:hover {
    background-color: #4AAE98;
    color: white;
}
```

and leave `.is-active` alone. This way the method:

```
  clearHoverSelection() {
    this.$refs.resultsList.querySelectorAll('.autocomplete-result').forEach((element, index) => {
      if (index !== this.selectedIndex) {
        element.classList.remove('is-active');
      }
    });
  },
```

finally works.

The cause of the problem: the style was defined with two things, `.is-active` and `.autocomplete-result:hover`, removing the first from the `classList` would not remove the second.

The `.is-active` class already takes care of everything here:

```
            <li v-for="(result, i) in results" 
                :key="i" 
                @click="selectItem()" 
                @mouseover="selectedIndex = i"
                class="autocomplete-result" 
                :class="{ 'is-active': i === selectedIndex }">
                {{ result }}
            </li>
```

So no need to control the same behavior with a second class.

Here we are seeing the result of an important principle in programming: each functionality should do only one thing and should do it well. The `.is-active` class was a late adding and I forget the detail of removing the `autocomplete-result:hover`.

Even if the solution was really simple, the cause of the problem was not so simple to figure out and this because of its simplicity. It seemed too simple to work.

Comment: clearHoverSelection is not even needed. The script works great without it. The hover was really the cause of all the problems. It's even simpler than it was.